# 信用度が低いユーザーをチャットに招待するには？

Tags: バグ, チャット

とある問題を解決するため、モデレーター権限で（プライベートの）チャットルームを新しく作り、[信用度が20未満](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)のユーザーをチャットに招待しようとしたのですが、できません。

"Explicit write access" を与えるにはどのように指定すれば良いでしょうか？

[image: Explicit write access]

[image: Add a new user to the write access list]

たとえばユーザーのプロフィールURLとして https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community のような URL を指定しても、何のログも出ず、ユーザーが追加されてもいません。

関連？: [Error with explicit chat write access for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194514/341401)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

指定するURLは恐らく **chat.stackexchange.com** 上でのアカウントURLです。

例えば私の場合は https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/278731/cubick となります。
(同じユーザーでも、数字の部分が各ネットワークごとへの登録順で異なる？)

追加時のプロンプトに説明が出ている通り、既に該当ユーザーがチャットにアクセスしていればユーザーIDなどで検索ができるみたいですが、そうでない場合が少し面倒で、モデレーター権限があれば(SOjaなどの)プロフィール画面から該当ユーザーの「Modダッシュボード」→「チャットプロフィール」でURLが確認できます。

Comment: ！！　確かにその手段を使ってユーザーが追加できたように表示されました。確かに見えているかどうかまだ分からないので、レスポンスあり次第回答を承認しますね。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

場当たり的ですが、モデレーターであれば以下の方法で　grant write access できるようです。

1. 招待したいチャットにおいて、superping をする。`@@https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu` のような感じで。この投稿をした段階では権限がついていないので警告が出たりします。これをすると chat 側にユーザー情報が作られるようです。
2. もう一度 superping をする。そうすると chat 側でのユーザー ID に補完されるので、この数字をコピーします。
3. コピーした ID を使って grant write access します。